# Android app can not be installed from the play store because of Google Play Services 8.3.0

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Recently I got some reports that one of our apps can not be installed from the Play Store. The error message is:

"App name" can't be installed. Try again, and if the problem continues, get help troubleshooting(Error code: -505)

[image: Error message]

The app was perfectly fine before the latest release and never faced similar problems with it.

Does this ring any bell to anyone?

**EDIT**:

This whole thing seems to be related to the new Google Play Services v8.3.0

Comment: Did you happen to click on the link they gave you?

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess that your answer lies at -505 in the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android 5.0 lollipop app install shows Unknown error code during application install: "-505"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491251/android-5-0-lollipop-app-install-shows-unknown-error-code-during-application-ins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some debugging, I found the problem which is the latest version of the Google Play Services, [version 8.3.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_2015_-_v83)

I downgraded Play Services to the latest stable release I had in the app ([GPS 8.1.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#september_2015_-_v81)) and sent out the new builds to users having the installation issues and they were able to instal the app successfully.

This seems to affect a few apps like Mixcloud too, but it could also mess up **Beta**, Fabric's app helping you distribute your app.

So for now, probably you should hold on with updating Google Play Services to 8.3.0 until they fix this.(?)

[Here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/the-beta-app-stopped-working-today-12-11-2015/56249) is a discussion with the Fabric team about the same thing.

**EDIT:**

Fabric fixed this bug in the version 1.5.1 of their **Beta** app.

Comment: I wanted to say thank you for finding this bug - this happened to us as well. I was wondering if you could briefly explain how you managed to debug this and find out that google play services was the culprit?

Comment: Hey Jon! If you check out my discussion with the Fabric team, you'll have enough details to understand all that.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this line to the app build.gradle solves this issue:

```
  defaultConfig {

applicationId "[app package]"
...

}
```